# Generic word for uni-, bi-, tricycle, etc.?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

Is there a generic word for bicycle-like vehicles that may have 1,2,3,4 or more wheels?

I want motorcycles excluded; only pedal-driven vehicles should be included.

Comment: It may be more complicated, depending on what you are trying to express. [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human-powered_land_vehicle) lists at least 11 types of wheeled, human powered vehicles, including rickshaws and skateboards. Are you limited to pedal driven? What about balance bikes? [Trikkes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trikke)?

Comment: Generally something along the line of "human-powered vehicle" is used.  Or "pedal-driven vehicle", if you feel you must be that specific.

Comment: How about a manually propelled conveyance?  Unfueled gyroscopic transport?  Hipstermobile?

Comment: Or one could use "omnicycle", except that the name has been co-opted by an "as seen on TV" exercise bike.

Comment: How about providing a sentence where you would use this word you seek?

Comment: Our legislators cannot find a suitable word. In the traffic act they define "bicycle" to include any number of wheels.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Some legislators use [Brian Drummond's answer.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/346725/115786)

Comment: I'd be tempted to suggest `n-cycle`

Comment: This is what you get for thoughtlessly adapting a word that is needlessly specific when the concept to be convey was essentially only "human powered driving thingy". Living languages be damned! ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Pedal cycle.

At least in British English, it is a recognised generic term, sometimes in a formal or legal context [such as insurance](http://www.cover4insurance.com/cycle-insurance)

Note that the examples of what is covered don't explicitly include numbers of wheels other than two, the term itself is not limited to 2 wheelers.

Comment: "Pedal cycle" is [not in anything close to common use](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Pedal+cycle%2Cvelocipede%2C+unicycle&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CPedal%20cycle%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpedal%20cycle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPedal%20cycle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPedal%20Cycle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cvelocipede%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvelocipede%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVelocipede%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVELOCIPEDE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cunicycle%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bunicycle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUnicycle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUNICYCLE%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I've seen it written in to some laws.

Comment: @Brock: [Kinda](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pedal+cycle%2Cunicycle&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpedal%20cycle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunicycle%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: The Traffic Signs Regulations and General Directions 1994 stated that a ‘pedal cycle’ was defined as “a unicycle, bicycle, tricycle, or cycle having four or more wheels, not being in any case mechanically propelled unless it is an electrically assisted pedal cycle of such class as is to be treated as not being a motor vehicle for the purposes of the 1984 Act.” - http://www.bikehub.co.uk/featured-articles/cycling-and-the-law/

Comment: @armb, that article you linked more often says things like: **`"Cycle Track is the most official term, as it’s used in the legislation noted above"`** and uses "Cycle lane", "Cycle track", "Cycle path", etc. as the "most official" terms.  Your reference supports Mithrandir's answer more than this answer. ... It looks like some Brit bureaucrats tried to coin the term "pedal cycle", but **it never caught on** and **"Velocipede" is still cited six times more often**. (See the first comment, above.)  Also, "pedal cycle" *seems* to be a mostly British thing.

Comment: @BrockAdams I wouldn't expect any term for "pedal-powered vehicle with any number of wheels" to be in common use, since the concept itself is not in common use. I live in a city where pedal-powered vehicles are extremely widely used. I'd say that I see a tricycle about once a month, a unicycle about once a year and I don't recall ever seeing something with four or more wheels. So, if I want a term for "pedal-powered vehicle with any number of wheels", I just say "bicycle", which covers 99.99% of what I'm talking about.

Comment: I agree that outside some official uses it's not in very common or popular use. But that's not what the question asked. We don't know the questioner's intent in asking the question. If it's for some formal purpose where British English is used, it's a suitable term. If it's for a steampunk convention, then go with Velocipede instead.

Comment: I just noticed this morning TFL API uses pedal cycle in it's collision data: https://blog.tfl.gov.uk/2016/03/07/london-collision-map-and-improved-cycle-journey-planning/

Comment: @BrockAdams - the comments under Mithrandir's answer suggest that the original questioner wanted something that unambiguously excludes motorcycles. (Strictly, even pedal cycle could include some mopeds. For example, the UK legal definition of "cycle track" is (in part) a way over which the public have "a right of way on pedal cycles (other than pedal cycles which are motor vehicles within the meaning of the Road Traffic Act 1988)".)
"Velocipede" might be more commonly used, but as AndyT's answer says, it's mainly used to mean something different.

Answer (score 70):

A **[velocipede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocipede)**:

> Velocipede (/vəˈlɒsəpiːd/; Latin for "fast foot") is a human-powered land vehicle with one or more wheels. The most common type of velocipede today is the bicycle.
>
> The term "velocipede" is today, however, mainly used as a collective term for the different forerunners of the monowheel, the unicycle, the bicycle, the dicycle, the tricycle and the quadracycle developed between 1817 and 1880.

[Wikipedia.org]

Note that this is unlikely to be understood by a wide audience. I knew the word existed, but I didn't know its exact definition until I researched it for this answer. I had suspected it was just a synonym for bicycle, and was quite happy to find out it was in fact its hypernym.

Comment: Huh, I always thought _velocipede_ was just another term for a penny-farthing.

Comment: I always thought *velocipede* was a synonym for *boneshaker*, an early bike that looks more like a modern bike than a penny-farthing. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocipede#Boneshaker) this is correct - "velocipede" was the manufacturer's term - though the word might also have taken on a more general meaning later.

Comment: I would have decoded "fast foot" and thought it was a quick bug.

Comment: I'm still pretty sad that Velocipede never caught on. It's so much of a better name than bicycle.

Comment: Velocipedes were pretty much rendered obsolete by the "Ordinary bicycle" or penny farthing. Which itself was obsoleted by chain drive which allowed appropriate gear ratios.

Comment: In Russian any pedal-driven bicycle is called velosiped.

Answer (score 34):

A **cycle**

> 4.
> a bicycle, motorcycle, tricycle, etc.
> <sub>-[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cycle?s=t)</sub>

*Note: This was posted* before *the exclusion of 'motorcycle'.*

Comment: I want motorcycle excluded, only pedal-driven vehicles shoud be included.

Comment: In that case, "pedal cycle"?

Comment: [Oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cycle) gives *A bicycle or tricycle*.  No mention of a motor--.  This fits with what I'm familiar with in the UK (where "bike" may be used for motorbike in context, but "cycle" isn't).

Comment: I assume you want to exclude hand cycles, balance bikes etc?

Comment: To the downvoter: This answer was posted before the exclusion of motor--.

Comment: **Cycling** is an extremely common term for the activity of riding a human powered n-cycle vehicle, and the common term for someone who rides such is **cyclist** so this answer is better than it may first appear. Cycling is widely recognized as excluding motorcycling. Furthermore, a common term for some motorcycle riders is **biker** and many motorcyclists refer to their vehicles as **bikes**.

Comment: @Anixx I've never heard the term *cycle* applied to a motorcycle, but maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 15):

Re:

> Is there a generic word for bicycle-like vehicles that may have 1, 2, 3, 4 or more wheels?

Technically, yes, see [AndyT's answer of "Velocipede"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/346347/).

But **practically, no there isn't.**
**Not every concept has, or needs a word in English.**  The proof is in [the fact that Velocipede never caught on](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Velocipede%2Ctricycle%2C%20bicycle&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CVelocipede%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvelocipede%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVelocipede%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVELOCIPEDE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ctricycle%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btricycle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTricycle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTRICYCLE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cbicycle%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbicycle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBicycle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBICYCLE%3B%2Cc0) (nor any word like it):

[image: Nobody uses that word]

---

Practically, the word "Bike" is close and and most people will get your meaning.

**"Bicycle" shops sell unicycles, bicycles, tricycles (AKA "trikes"), and quadracycles ([AKA "Car-Bike" or "Twin bike", among other aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadracycle#Nomenclature)).**

Of course, "Bike" can also mean motorbike.  Again, this hints that there is no real need for a unique term.

---

In terms of: ease of use, (human) power requirements, safety, efficiency, stowability, and support infrastructure, there are huge differences between 1, 2, 3, and 4 wheeled, human-powered vehicles (HPV).  Likewise, 5 or more wheels would almost never be a good engineering/ergonomic solution for an HPV**.

So, it makes a great deal of sense to keep separate terms for such devices. They are markedly different experiences from the rider and owner perspectives.

---

** HPV does not answer the question since it also [applies to vast hoards of watercraft, aircraft, etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human-powered_transport#Human-powered_vehicles_.28HPVs.29).

Answer (score 9):

HPV. Human Powered Vehicle. This is as broad a term as you can get as long as you aren't worried about circus bicycles ridden by animals.

Vehicle types covered by the [WHPVA](http://www.whpva.org/vehicle-types.html)

Comment: This would include human powered aircraft and submarines.

Comment: @stannius, and also paddle-boats, rowboats, canoes, skis, balance/circus balls, etc.

Comment: I wouldn't use that [acronym](http://www.cdc.gov/hpv/parents/whatishpv.html).

Comment: @Laurel Who wants to ride the Human PapillomaVirus?

Comment: In the context of cycling, *HPV* tends to refer to pedal-powered vehicle with significantly better aerodynamic performance (and therefore speed) than a normal bicycle. These tend to be experimental and not suited to riding on open roads. So the term isn't a good fit to many likely contexts for the question.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently there was once the word [push-cycle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/push-cycle), which is probably exactly the word you want - it doesn't mention the number of wheels, and the "push" excludes the motor-driven ones.
But it is not very widespread. Many dictionaries don't mention it at all, and this non-native speaker certainly never heard of it until I stumbled across it just now!

[pushbike](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pushbike) would be better understood, at least in BE, but this one does mention the number of wheels. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

DMV manuals often refer to ["**non-motorized** vehicles"](http://nj1015.com/nj-drivers-urged-to-review-online-drivers-manual/), but they are not limited to pedal-driven vehicles.